# Error message when persisting entity with EmbbededID in Many To One relationship

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm developing a project in JSF, and I'm trying to persist this Entity below, but I'm receiving a error message. Before I created the relationship, the Conta class was persisting correctly, but with the Many To One with Transacao, I can't.

This is the Transacao class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
private Conta contaOrigem;
private String agenciaDestino;
private String contaDestino;
private String cpfDestino;
...
```

This is the Conta class:

```
public class Conta {

@EmbeddedId
private DadosConta contaUsuario = new DadosConta();
@NotEmpty(message="Senha não pode estar em branco")
private String senha;
@NotEmpty(message="Selecione uma opção")
private String tipoConta;
private double saldo;
private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
@OneToMany(mappedBy="contaOrigem", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Transacao> transacoes = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

And the DadosConta (Embedded ID class):

```
@Embeddable
public class DadosConta implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7021727065659352073L;
@NotEmpty
private String agencia;
@NotEmpty
private String conta;
...
```

And finally, this is the error:

```
Foreign key (FK_8k5jlptboiq6xm4oopg9jnh2l:Transacao [contaOrigem])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (conta [agencia,conta])
```

I know that the error message is "explicit", but I don't know how can I persist this Many to One relationship with EmbeddedId, is there any workaround?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `Transacao` class to complete the bi-directional join.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "agencia"), @JoinColumn(name = "conta")})
private Conta contaOrigem;
```